# Class 'does not name a type' error in template file

Tags: c++, templates

I've been trying to work out the cause of an error I'm getting in the compiler, stating in the template file "Node.template" that '`node<Obj>` does not name a type'.

I am new to class templates and have looked around for answers but I'm still not able to fix this particular problem.

Here's code for the two files:

```
//Node.h
#ifndef NODE_CAMERON_H
#define NODE_CAMERON_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace oreilly_A2 {
    template <typename Obj>
class node {

public:
typedef std::string value_type;

node(); //constructor for node

node(const value_type& val, Obj* newNext); //constructor with parameters

void set_data(const value_type& new_data); //set the word that this node contains

void set_link(Obj* new_link); //set the 'next' Obj
void set_previous(Obj* new_prev);

value_type data() const; //return this node's word

const Obj* link() const; //return next

const Obj* back() const;

Obj* link(); //return next

Obj* back(); 

private:

Obj* next; //the next Obj
Obj* previous;
value_type word; //the word this node contains

};
}
#include "Node.template"
#endif
```

Node.template file:

```
//Node.template
template <typename Obj>
node<Obj>::node(const node::value_type& val=value_type(), Obj* newNext=NULL) {
    word = val;
    next = newNext;
}

template <typename Obj>
node<Obj>::~node() {}

template <typename Obj>
void node<Obj>::set_data(const value_type& new_data){
        word = new_data;
}


template <typename Obj>
void node<Obj>::set_link(Obj* new_link){
        next = new_link;

}


template <typename Obj>
void node<Obj>::set_previous(Obj* new_prev) {
        previous = new_back;
}


template <typename Obj>
value_type node<Obj>::data() const {  //return the word
        return word;
}


template <typename Obj>
const Obj* node<Obj>::link() const { //return next node (const function)
        return next;
}


template <typename Obj>
const Obj* node<Obj>::back() const { //return previous node (const)
        return previous;
}


template <typename Obj>
Obj* node<Obj>::link() {
        return next; //return next node (non-const)
}


template <typename Obj>
Obj* node<Obj>::back() { //return previous node (const)
        return previous;
}
```

Comment: When defining that you are using namespace std there is no reason for you to have std::string. You can simply put string. I would think it is bad coding practice to include namespaces in your header files as there can be conflicts with other namespaces further down the line. For instance, if you include your header in your main cpp and then decide to use namespace boost. Your program will have issues with functions. Such as std::begin() and boost::begin(). This issue is removed by using the namespace before the function but then if you're going to so that you don't need "using namespace std;".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared the class template inside a namespace…

…but forgot the namespace when you defined its member functions.

There are indeed no types named `node<Obj>`, only types named `oreilly_A2::node<Obj>` (∀ `Obj`).

**You need `namespace oreilly_A2 {` `}` in *Node.template*.**

Also, please stop writing `using namespace std` in header files.